# Django redirect from form upload

Tags: django, heroku

From the page

```
This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405
```

From the terminal

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
[20/Dec/2021 22:00:27] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

How to redirect to the same page after page upload click.

form.html->included in sidebar.html-> included in home.html

```
<form method = "POST" action='.' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserProfileForm

def index(request):
    print(request.POST)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView # new

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), 
]
```

Comment: Can you add your `urls.py`? A 405 means the method was not allowed so the view that handled the request did not accept POST requests

Comment: Ok added the urls.py.

Comment: You have a `TemplateView` serving that path and it does not accept POST requests. The view in your question is not used at all

Comment: Should I swap it to view and it should work kind of new to django stuff.

Comment: You need to swap the TemplateView for a view that can handle GET and POST requests, a FormView might work or just a standard view

Comment: Using index for the url.py did work is there any reason to not use this or is it fine.

Comment: Yes it's fine, you should make sure that you return a redirect after a POST though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls.py

Change to:

path(' ', index, name = 'home'),

And you also have to import your view in urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Since you are redirecting to the same page, I assume you are also making a get request when you are serving the form on the webpage.
But when the page is served as a response to a GET request, it is not supposed to contain an empty dictionary in the POST attribute.
Thus, it provides an error.
According to me

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        print(request.POST)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Should solve the issue

Acc, to the Django documentation

It’s possible that a request can come in via POST with an empty POST dictionary – if, say, a form is requested via the POST HTTP method but does not include form data. Therefore, you shouldn’t use if request.POST to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if request.method == "POST"

For further reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/

Comment: It does show my querydict for the post but the main reason was the urls.py.